# How to remove characters in a string after first number that is encountered

Tags: python-2.7

This should be easy. I have hostnames such as:

hostfoo1234.blah.com

hostbar9999.blah.com

hostbazz0489.blah.com

How can I use regex to remove everything after the first digit is encountered, including the first digit? The first number can be anything, 0-9. Output should be:

hostfoo

hostbar

hostbazz

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without regex

```
def removeAfterFirstNumber(hostname):
    res = []
    for i in range(0,len(hostname)): 
        if hostname[i].isdigit()is not True:            
            res.append(hostname[i])
        else:
            break

    return "".join(res)


a="hostbazz0489.blah.com"

print (removeAfterFirstNumber(a))

## output
hostbazz
```

or using re library

```
import re

def removeAfterFirstNumber(hostname):
    m = re.search("\d", hostname)     
    return hostname[:m.start()] if m else hostname

a="hostbazz0489.blah.com"
print (removeAfterFirstNumber(a))

## output
hostbazz
```

Comment: That wasn't easy at all, but worked like a charm. Used Re. Much appreciated @DavidZambrano!